# Elegant way to copy properties from object to another

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a small integration service which recieves XML files and parses it.
Also I've created classes from provided XSD for deserializing XML data. During parsing I need to copy properties from those XSD-generated classes to my own that I use in Data Layer. This is an example of my aproach

```
var supplierInfo = new SupplierInfo();
//coping properties
supplierInfo.Name = supplier.name;
supplierInfo.ShortName = supplier.shortName;
supplierInfo.BrandName = supplier.brandName;
supplierInfo.AdditionalFullName = supplier.additionalFullName;
supplierInfo.AdditionalCode = supplier.additionalCode;
supplierInfo.AdditionalInfo = supplier.additionalInfo;
//lot's of other properties
//...
supplierInfo.Tax = supplier.tax;
supplierInfo.RegistrationDate = supplier.registrationDate;
```

Some times ammount of properties is very big. Is there more eligant way to copy those properties?

Comment: As far as I know there's not really a way to do it without using `System.Reflection`, and reflection calls are quite slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automapper has been out there since ages ago. Tried and tested. http://automapper.org/

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;   

public class Program
{
    class SupplierInfo
    {
        public SupplierInfo( string name, string shortName, string brandName ) {
            Name = name; 
            ShortName = shortName; 
            BrandName = brandName;
        }
        public string Name {get; private set; }
        public string ShortName {get; private set; }
        public string BrandName {get; private set; }
    }

    class Supplier
    {
        public string name {get; set; }
        public string shortName {get; set; }
        public string brandName {get; set; }
    }       

    public static void Main()
    {
        var dto = new Supplier() {
            name = "Name 1",
            shortName = "Short Name 1",
            brandName = "Brand Name 1"
        };


        //From the tutorial:
        //You only need one MapperConfiguration instance typically per AppDomain and should be instantiated during startup.
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Supplier, SupplierInfo>());

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        SupplierInfo info = mapper.Map<SupplierInfo>(dto);

        Console.WriteLine( info.Name );
        Console.WriteLine( info.ShortName );
        Console.WriteLine( info.BrandName );
    }
}
```

The official Getting Started guide can be found at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: This is a link only answer and they are strongly discouraged on SO.

Comment: Posting some link without any explanation or example will not be very useful to OP, I suppose.

Comment: this makes me sad because it actively encourages people to turn their business objects into stupid "dto"s that are nothing more than glorified property bags. I would trade the "convenience" (that will come back and bite you) of this for writing a factory, getting guaranteed encapsulation and easier architecture to understand and reason about any day.

Comment: @kai Firstly, one cannot turn a business object into a dto. It's one or another :) Secondly, I think you're making a giant mental leap from the problem of tedious copying to incorrectly implemented business domains.

Comment: which is why I quoted it. an object with only public getters/setters and no methods is no different from a simple C struct or a DTO. I am referring to the fact that AutoMapper wants you to give up encapsulation in order to save a few keystrokes. I think it's irresponsible.

Answer (score 1):

First, install EntityLite.Core:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityLite.Core
```

Then use it:

```
using inercya.EntityLite.Extensions;
...
supplierInfo.AssignPropertiesFrom(supplier);
```

[EntityLite](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/753796/i-nercya-EntityLite-A-Lightweight-Database-First-M) is a micro ORM I developed. It has some little gems :-)

EDIT:

I guess you may not want to install `EntityLite.Core` just to copy some properties from an object to another. So here you have an implementation of `AssignPropertiesFrom` extension method that uses Reflection:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static void AssignPropertiesForm(this object target, object source)
    {
        if (target == null || source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var targetPropertiesDic = target.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite).ToDictionary(p => p.Name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        foreach (var sourceProp in source.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead))
        {
            PropertyInfo targetProp;
            if (targetPropertiesDic.TryGetValue(sourceProp.Name, out targetProp))
            {
                targetProp.SetValue(target, sourceProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Incidentally, this is not the EntityLite implementation. EntityLite uses dynamic IL generation.

Answer (score 1):

I am happy to be corrected on this but I always find automapper (as per the other answer), which maps property values by name/convention, a little scary to use in production code.

I don't really have a decent alternative but I prefer to do it manually as per your code sample - it's easier to read and debug and if you end up renaming any properties in a class, it will be clear that the copying code is broken (or if you use some IDE tool to rename the property, it'll change the copy code accordingly).

Comment: How is Automapper scary?!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, if I rename a property on one of the classes and not on the other, that property will stop getting mapped within AutoMapper. Unless ofcourse you've manually defined the mappings in which case you end up with the same/similar code as manually mapping it?

Comment: Sure if you go round changing things like that, but if you do that without testing your code before it hits production, that's waaaaaay more scary...

Comment: Sure but it's just another vector for mistakes and test breaks. I'm not saying that AutoMapper doesn't have its place but in large code bases with many developers, in my opinion, it doesn't add a great deal in the long run.

Comment: Well if you want to write tonnes of boilerplate code then go ahead, I'll save my fingers for something a little more fun! I've used this in several very large projects with big dev teams and have yet to regret it.

Comment: @ jamespconnor Fair point of view, but the alternative is writing things by hand and it IS error prone.

Comment: automapper is scary because it's black magic. any framework that claims "you don't need to worry, things will just work, we'll just read your property names and figure things out" is an accident waiting to happen.

yes, code should be tested, but these bugs can be awfully subtle. I think the overhead of writing mapping code manually is highly overrated, and if it's such a bother, it's possibly the design you need to worry about. I've dealt with automapper in production code and my thoughts now are to stay away.

Comment: not to mention the fact that these types of mapping frameworks often FORCE you to make all your business objects mutable messes with public setters for all properties (unless your want to do a whole bunch of manual configuring, but that that point, why would you introduce the extra dependency to begin with?)